# how can I zip a list of random numbers with a list of pairs haskell

Tags: haskell

```
module Meth where
import System.Random
import Data.List

type Dom = (Int,Int) 


gen :: StdGen
gen = mkStdGen 10

dominoes :: [Dom]  
dominoes = [(x, y)| x <- [0..6], y <- [x..6]]

shuffles:: StdGen->[Int] 
shuffles g = take 28 $ randoms g :: [Int]
```

I have created a list of 28 random numbers and I want to zip it with my List of [Dom] and sort it any help please. I don't know how to proceed from this point

Comment: `zipped :: StdGen -> [(Dom, Int)]`; `zipped g = zip dominoes $ shuffles g`?  You can then use `sortBy (Data.Ord.comparing snd)`, or however you want to sort it.

Comment: I recommend you use [`shuffleM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-shuffle-0.0.4/docs/System-Random-Shuffle.html#v:shuffleM) from the `random-shuffle` package, or [`shuffle`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.2.6.1/docs/Data-Random-List.html#v:shuffle) from `random-fu`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to sort it based on the number, you can simply make a function that uses `zip` and then `sortBy` to get the result:

```
result :: StdGen -> [(Dom, Int)]
result g =
    let zipped = zip dominoes (shuffles g)
    in sortBy (compare `on` snd) zipped
```